# Make dir in C, linux doesnt create sub-dirs (dir tree) - why?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, mkdir

I want to create a dir tree in C on linux. I wrote that code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int dirExists(const char *path)
{
    struct stat info;

    if(stat( path, &info ) != 0)
        return 0;
    else if(info.st_mode & S_IFDIR)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *path = "./mydir/firstdir/";

    if(!dirExists(path))
    {
        mode_t mask = umask(0);
        if(mkdir(path, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO) == -1)
            exit(-1);
        umask(mask);
    }

    printf("%d\n", dirExists(path));
    return 0;
}
```

Its ok when a `path` is a single dir, lets say, `path = "./mydir"` but when I want to create a dir tree, for example: `path = "./mydir/a/b/c/d/"` dirs are not created. Why?

Comment: mkdir does not recursively create directories like you are trying to do. It only creates one directory per call, and the parent dir has to already exist. You will need to modify your code to call mkdir one time for each directory you are creating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define code that is able to create a directory tree. In other word Mkdir doesn't create directory recursively.

**EDIT:**
In the link you've posted the parent directory already exists.

Comment: Ok, but here theres an example where I can use `mkdir` to create a dir tree: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html. Thats why I used it for it.

Answer (score 6):

You have no code to create a directory tree, so your code doesn't create a directory tree. If you want to create a directory tree, write code to do that.

Comment: +1 I *love* this answer. How many times have I been tempted to write "Write some code to solve your problem." as an answer, only to hold back for fear of the ensuing flame. Thanks for making my day, David =P

Comment: "That code, it does not do what you think/say/claim it does."

Answer (score 2):

What you do is create a folder who 's path is `path`

Comment: I was going to tease you for the "floder" typo, but [apparently "floder" is an actual word in Dutch](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/floder). That said, -1 for failing to answer the OPs question: I can't see how multiple rivers and/or floods will help to create a directory tree.

Comment: @Casey Sorry it is a typo, I has a little cold and headache now.

Comment: @Jongware Err, Danish + Swedish = Dutch. The proof of this fact is riveting, but too long to fit in this margin.